# Add mode to display resolution set

Tags: vmware, display-resolution, vmware-workstation

I have Ubuntu 16.04.6 and Ubuntu 18.04.2 in my vmware machine.

Resolution in Ubuntu 16 is fine:

```
1440x2560     60.00*+
2560x1600     59.99  
1920x1440     60.00  
1856x1392     60.00  
1792x1344     60.00  
1920x1200     59.88  
1600x1200     60.00  
1680x1050     59.95  
1400x1050     59.98  
1280x1024     60.02  
1440x900      59.89  
1280x960      60.00  
1360x768      60.02  
1280x800      59.81  
1152x864      75.00  
1280x768      59.87  
1024x768      60.00  
800x600       60.32  
640x480       59.94
```

Resolution in Ubuntu 18 is wrong:

```
   800x600       60.00*+  60.32  
   2560x1600     59.99  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.00  
   1792x1344     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x768      59.87  
   1024x768      60.00  
   640x480       59.94
```

Why Ubuntu 18 has no mode `1440x2560` ? How to fix that?

Comment: Can you please be specific on release of Ubuntu.  Do you mean Ubuntu Core 16 & Ubuntu Core 18 (one of the releases of Ubuntu that has a *yy* format name) or the more common Ubuntu *yy,mm* release.  Ubuntu Core 16 & 18 releases are usually used headless.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.6 and Ubuntu 18.04.2